# How to create a polyline with one end tracking the mouse pointer

Tags: silverlight, polyline

Suppose one end of my polyline is fixed say at 0,0, and when I move the mouse I want the polyline's other end to be on my mousepointer exactly.  What should I do in this case?

Sorry I am very new to Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Windows.Point staticPoint = new System.Windows.Point(100, 100);
System.Windows.Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(CanvasContainer);

PointCollection polygonPoints = new PointCollection();
polygonPoints.Add(staticPoint);
polygonPoints.Add(mousePoint);

polyline.Points = polygonPoints;
```